# Creating A Mobile Contacts/Messages Sync Server?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, nokia

I have been thinking of creating a web application that can enable users to backup their messages and phone contacts, just like Nokia's OVI sync. What kind of technology can one deploy to enable this, all the clients are expected to do is to enter the sync server settings on the phone and it will connect to the server and start the sync.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at [SyncML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncML) on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Windows Phone 7 does not support API access to messages or contacts so you will not be able to create an app to do this on WP7.

You may also want to note that different platforms do not store the same information about contacts and so it will not even be possible to sync all the information to all platforms.
You will also need to consider devices which allow the user to only save contact information to the SIM card. In this scenario you'll have much less contact data and probably the ability to save many fewer contacts.